@Remove a JsonProperty from a class file - Java
I am trying to implement a simple shopping cart system for a website. I am using a Spring framework and Rest API to do the backend for the website. The shopping cart must have the ability to be sterilized and desterilized from a file so that users can log off and back on and still retain their shopping cart items. In my case, the shopping cart is filled with Need objects that function similar to items put in the cart.
At first I tried to implement my shopping cart this way:
package com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
/**
 * Represents a Cart entity
 */
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "needs"})
public class Cart {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Cart.class.getName());

    // Package private for tests
    static final String STRING_FORMAT = "Cart [id=%d, needsArr=%s]";

    @JsonProperty("id") private int id;
    @JsonProperty("needs") private ArrayList<Need> needs;


    /**
     * Create a cart with the given id and map of needs.
     * @param id the id of the cart
     * @param needs the list of needs in the cart.
     * 
     * {@literal @} JsonProperty is used in serialization and deserialization
     * of the JSON object to the Java object in mapping the fields.  If a field
     * is not provided in the JSON object, the Java field gets the default Java
     * value, i.e. 0 for int.
     */
    public Cart(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty("needs") ArrayList<Need> needs) {
        this.id = id;
        this.needs = needs;
    }

    /**
     * Creates and empty cart with the given id.
     * @param id the id of the cart.
     */
    public Cart(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.needs = new ArrayList<Need>();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the id of the cart
     * @return the id of the cart
     */
    public int getId() {return id;}

    /**
     * Retrieves the needs in the cart
     * @return An array of needs in the cart
     */
    public Need[] getneeds() {
        return (Need[])(needs.toArray());
    }

    public Boolean addNeed(Need n) {
        for (Need need: needs)
        {
            if(n.getId() == need.getId()) { return false; }
        }
        needs.add(n);
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean updateNeed(Need n) {
        for (Need need: needs)
        {
            if(n.getId() == need.getId())
            {
                need.setQuantity(n.getQuantity());
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Boolean deleteNeed(int id) {
        for (Need need: needs)
        {
            if(id == need.getId())
            {
                return needs.remove(need);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void checkout() {
        needs.clear();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format(STRING_FORMAT, id, needs.toString());
    }
}

Which gave the error: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [Lcom.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Need; ([Ljava.lang.Object; is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap'; [Lcom.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Need; is in unnamed module of loader 'app') (through reference chain: com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Cart[0]->com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Cart["needs"])
This error was strange since the Need class has its on independent file saving functionality which works perfectly. I assumed that @jsonProperty must only allow for privative datatypes so I converted and stubbed out the code to use the privative datatype String to sterilize the data:
package com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
/**
 * Represents a Cart entity
 * 
 */
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "needsArr"})
public class Cart {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Cart.class.getName());

    // Package private for tests
    static final String STRING_FORMAT = "Cart [id=%d, needsArr=%s]";

    @JsonProperty("id") private int id;
    @JsonProperty("needsArr") private String needsArr;
    private ArrayList<int[]> needs;


    /**
     * Create a cart with the given id and map of needs.
     * @param id the id of the cart
     * @param needsArr the list of needs in the cart.
     * 
     * {@literal @} JsonProperty is used in serialization and deserialization
     * of the JSON object to the Java object in mapping the fields.  If a field
     * is not provided in the JSON object, the Java field gets the default Java
     * value, i.e. 0 for int.
     */
    public Cart(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty("needsArr") String needsArr) {
        this.id = id;
        needs = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        this.needsArr = needsArr;
    }

    /**
     * Creates and empty cart with the given id.
     * @param id the id of the cart.
     */
    public Cart(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.needs = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        needsArr = "";
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the id of the cart
     * @return the id of the cart
     */
    public int getId() {return id;}

    /**
     * Retrieves the needs in the cart
     * @return An array of needs in the cart
     */
    public int[][] getneeds() {
        return (int[][])(needs.toArray());
    }

    public Boolean addNeed(Need n) {
        for (int[] need: needs)
        {
            if(n.getId() == need[0]) { return false; }
        }
        needs.add(new int[]{n.getId(),
            n.getQuantity()});
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean updateNeed(Need n) {
        for (int[] need: needs)
        {
            if(n.getId() == need[0])
            {
                need[1] = n.getQuantity();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Boolean deleteNeed(int id) {
        for (int[] need: needs)
        {
            if(id == need[0])
            {
                return needs.remove(need);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void checkout() {
        needs.clear();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format(STRING_FORMAT, id, needsArr);
    }
}

This gave the error: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [[I ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [[I are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') (through reference chain: com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Cart[0]->com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Cart["needs"])
This made no sense because I have eliminated the @JsonProperty "needs" and replaced it with "needsArr"
I decided to stub out an implementation that only had two class varriables to see if that was it. This meathod if implemented would only store a string locally to represent my array of Needs and would have to be converted to an array every time an operation on the Needs were done:
package com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
/**
 * Represents a Cart entity
 * 
 */
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id", "needs"})
public class Cart {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Cart.class.getName());

    // Package private for tests
    static final String STRING_FORMAT = "Cart [id=%d, needs=%s]";

    @JsonProperty("id") private int id;
    @JsonProperty("needs") private String needs;


    /**
     * Create a cart with the given id and map of needs.
     * @param id the id of the cart
     * @param needs the list of needs in the cart.
     * 
     * {@literal @} JsonProperty is used in serialization and deserialization
     * of the JSON object to the Java object in mapping the fields.  If a field
     * is not provided in the JSON object, the Java field gets the default Java
     * value, i.e. 0 for int.
     */
    public Cart(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty("needs") String needs) {
        this.id = id;
        this.needs = needs;
    }

    /**
     * Creates and empty cart with the given id.
     * @param id the id of the cart.
     */
    public Cart(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.needs = "[]";
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the id of the cart
     * @return the id of the cart
     */
    public int getId() {return id;}

    /**
     * Retrieves the needs in the cart
     * @return An array of needs in the cart
     */
    public int[][] getneeds() {
        return (int[][])(decode().toArray());
    }

    public Boolean addNeed(Need n) {
        ArrayList<int[]> needArr = decode();
        for (int[] need: needArr)
        {
            if(n.getId() == need[0]) { return false; }
        }
        needArr.add(new int[]{n.getId(),
            n.getQuantity()});
        encode(needArr);
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean updateNeed(Need n) {
        ArrayList<int[]> needArr = decode();
        for (int[] need: needArr)
        {
            if(n.getId() == need[0])
            {
                need[1] = n.getQuantity();
                encode(needArr);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Boolean deleteNeed(int id) {
        ArrayList<int[]> needArr = decode();
        for (int[] need: needArr)
        {
            if(id == need[0] && needArr.remove(need))
            {
                encode(needArr);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void checkout() {
        needs = "[]";
    }

    private void encode(ArrayList<int[]> needs) {
        this.needs = "[]";
    }

    private ArrayList<int[]> decode() {
        return new ArrayList<int[]>();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format(STRING_FORMAT, id, needs);
    }
}

This once again received the error: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [[I ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [[I are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') (through reference chain: com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Cart[0]->com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Cart["needs"]) 
I was so confused this this mystery problem with the needs variable that I tried just removing it entirely making the cart non-functional.
package com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
/**
 * Represents a Cart entity
 * 
 */
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "id"})//, "needs"})
public class Cart {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Cart.class.getName());

    // Package private for tests
    static final String STRING_FORMAT = "Cart [id=%d]";//, needs=%s]";

    @JsonProperty("id") private int id;
    //@JsonProperty("needs") private String needs;


    /**
     * Create a cart with the given id and map of needs.
     * @param id the id of the cart
     * @param needs the list of needs in the cart.
     * 
     * {@literal @} JsonProperty is used in serialization and deserialization
     * of the JSON object to the Java object in mapping the fields.  If a field
     * is not provided in the JSON object, the Java field gets the default Java
     * value, i.e. 0 for int.
     */
    public Cart(@JsonProperty("id") int id) {//, @JsonProperty("needs") String needs) {
        this.id = id;
        //this.needs = needs;
    }

    /**
     * Creates and empty cart with the given id.
     * @param id the id of the cart.
     */
    /*public Cart(int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.needs = "[]";
    }*/

    /**
     * Retrieves the id of the cart
     * @return the id of the cart
     */
    public int getId() {return id;}

    /**
     * Retrieves the needs in the cart
     * @return An array of needs in the cart
     */
    public int[][] getneeds() {
        return (int[][])(decode().toArray());
    }

    public Boolean addNeed(Need n) {
        ArrayList<int[]> needArr = decode();
        for (int[] need: needArr)
        {
            if(n.getId() == need[0]) { return false; }
        }
        needArr.add(new int[]{n.getId(),
            n.getQuantity()});
        encode(needArr);
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean updateNeed(Need n) {
        ArrayList<int[]> needArr = decode();
        for (int[] need: needArr)
        {
            if(n.getId() == need[0])
            {
                need[1] = n.getQuantity();
                encode(needArr);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Boolean deleteNeed(int id) {
        ArrayList<int[]> needArr = decode();
        for (int[] need: needArr)
        {
            if(id == need[0] && needArr.remove(need))
            {
                encode(needArr);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public void checkout() {
        //needs = "[]";
    }

    private void encode(ArrayList<int[]> needs) {
        //this.needs = "[]";
    }

    private ArrayList<int[]> decode() {
        return new ArrayList<int[]>();
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format(STRING_FORMAT, id);//, needs);
    }
}

This gave the error: class [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to class [[I ([Ljava.lang.Object; and [[I are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap') (through reference chain: com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Cart[0]->com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Cart["needs"])
This actually doesn't make sense. I eliminated every mention of the needs class variable and the object mapper is still trying to implement it. Does anyone know how this is happening and a possible way that I could fix this problem?
In case they are necessary here is the class that is writing the Carts to a file and the Need class as well:
package com.ufund.api.ufundapi.persistence;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Cart;
import com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model.Need;

/**
 * Implements the functionality for JSON file-based peristance for cart
 * 
 * {@literal @}Component Spring annotation instantiates a single instance of this
 * class and injects the instance into other classes as Carted
 */
@Component
public class CartFileDAO implements CartDAO {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(CartFileDAO.class.getName());
    Map<Integer,Cart> cartPark;   // Provides a local cache of the cartPark
                                  // so that we don't need to read from the file
                                  // each time
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;  // Provides conversion between Cart
            // objects and JSON text format written
            // to the file
    private String filename;    // Filename to read from and write to

    /**
     * Creates a Cart File Data Access Object
     * 
     * @param filename Filename to read from and write to
     * @param objectMapper Provides JSON Object to/from Java Object serialization and deserialization
     * 
     * @throws IOException when file cannot be accessed or read from
     */
    public CartFileDAO(@Value("${cartPark.file}") String filename, ObjectMapper objectMapper) throws IOException {
        this.filename = filename;
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
        load();  // load the cartPark from the file
    }

    /**
     * Generates an array of {@linkplain Cart carts} from the tree map for any
     * {@linkplain Cart carts}.
     * 
     * @return  The array of {@link Cart carts}, may be empty.
     */
    private Cart[] getcartParkArray() { // if containsText == null, no filter
        ArrayList<Cart> cartArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        for (Cart cart : cartPark.values()) {
            cartArrayList.add(cart);
        }

        Cart[] cartArray = new Cart[cartArrayList.size()];
        cartArrayList.toArray(cartArray);
        return cartArray;
    }

    /**
     * Saves the {@linkplain Cart carts} from the cartPark into the file as an array of JSON objects
     * 
     * @return true if the {@link Cart carts} were written successfully
     * 
     * @throws IOException when file cannot be accessed or written to
     */
    private boolean save() throws IOException {
        Cart[] CartArray = getcartParkArray();

        // Serializes the Java Objects to JSON objects into the file
        // writeValue will thrown an IOException if there is an issue
        // with the file or reading from the file
        objectMapper.writeValue(new File(filename),CartArray);
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Loads {@linkplain Cart carts} from the JSON file into the cartPark
     * <br>
     * Also sets next id to one more than the greatest id found in the file
     * 
     * @return true if the file was read successfully
     * 
     * @throws IOException when file cannot be accessed or read from
     */
    private boolean load() throws IOException {
        cartPark = new TreeMap<>();

        // Deserializes the JSON objects from the file into an array of car
        // readValue will throw an IOException if there's an issue with the file
        // or reading from the file
        Cart[] CartArray = objectMapper.readValue(new File(filename),Cart[].class);

        // Add each Cart to the tree map and keep track of the greatest id
        for (Cart Cart : CartArray) {
            cartPark.put(Cart.getId(),Cart);
        }
        return true;
    }

    /**
    ** {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Need[] getCart(int id, NeedDAO needDAO) throws IOException {
        synchronized(cartPark) {
            Cart cart = cartPark.get(id);
            if(cart == null)
            {
                return null;
            }
            int[][] needs = cart.getneeds();
            Need[] needsArr = new Need[needs.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < needs.length; i++) {
                Need need = needDAO.getNeed(needs[i][0]);
                need.setQuantity(needs[i][1]);
                needsArr[i] = need;
            }
            return needsArr;
        }
    }

    /**
    ** {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean createCart(int id) throws IOException {
        synchronized(cartPark) {
            if(cartPark.containsKey(id)) {
                return false;
            }
            Cart newCart = new Cart(id);
            cartPark.put(newCart.getId(),newCart);
            save(); // may throw an IOException
            return true;

        }
    }

    /**
    ** {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean addNeed(int cId, int nId, NeedDAO needDAO) throws IOException {
        synchronized(cartPark) {
            Need need = needDAO.getNeed(nId);
            if(need == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return cartPark.get(cId).addNeed(need) && save();
        }
    }

    /**
    ** {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean updateNeed(int id, Need n) throws IOException {
        synchronized(cartPark) {
            Cart cart = cartPark.get(id);
            if(cart == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return cart.updateNeed(n) && save();
        }
    }

    /**
    ** {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean deleteNeed(int cId, int nId) throws IOException {
        synchronized(cartPark) {
            Cart cart = cartPark.get(cId);
            if(cart == null) {
                return false;
            }
            return cart.deleteNeed(nId) && save();
        }
    }

    /**
    ** {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean checkout(int id) throws IOException {
        synchronized(cartPark) {
            Cart cart = cartPark.get(id);
            if(cart == null) {
                return false;
            }
            cart.checkout();
            return save();
        }
    }

    /**
    ** {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public Boolean deleteCart(int id) throws IOException {
        synchronized(cartPark) {
            return cartPark.remove(id) != null && save();
        }
    }
}

package com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model;

import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
/**
 * Represents a Need entity
 * 
 */
public class Need {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Need.class.getName());

    // Package private for tests
    static final String STRING_FORMAT = "Need [id=%d, name=%s, type=%s, cost=%d, quantity=%d]";

    @JsonProperty("id") private int id;
    @JsonProperty("name") private String name;
    @JsonProperty("type") private String type;
    @JsonProperty("cost") private int cost;
    @JsonProperty("quantity") private int quantity;

    /**
     * Create a need with the given id, name, type, cost, and quantity.
     * @param id The id of the need
     * @param name The name of the need
     * @param type The type of the type
     * @param cost The name of the cost
     * @param quantity The name of the quantity
     * 
     * {@literal @}JsonProperty is used in serialization and deserialization
     * of the JSON object to the Java object in mapping the fields.  If a field
     * is not provided in the JSON object, the Java field gets the default Java
     * value, i.e. 0 for int
     */
    public Need(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty("name") String name, @JsonProperty("type") String type,
    @JsonProperty("cost") int cost, @JsonProperty("quantity") int quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.cost = cost;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.type = type;
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves the id of the need
     * @return The id of the need
     */
    public int getId() {return id;}

    /**
     * Sets the name of the need - necessary for JSON object to Java object deserialization
     * @param name The name of the need
     */
    public void setName(String name) {this.name = name;}

    /**
     * Retrieves the name of the need
     * @return The name of the need
     */
    public String getName() {return name;}

    /**
     * Retrieves the type of the need
     * @return The type of the need
     */
    public String getType() {return type;}

    /**
     * Sets the type of the need - necessary for JSON object to Java object deserialization
     * @param name The type of the need
     */
    public void setType(String type) {this.type = type;}

    /**
     * Retrieves the cost of the need
     * @return The cost of the need
     */
    public int getCost() {return cost;}

    /**
     * Retrieves the quantity of the need
     * @return The quantity of the need
     */
    public int getQuantity() {return quantity;}

    /**
     * Sets the cost of the need - necessary for JSON object to Java object deserialization
     * @param cost The cost of the need
     */
    public void setCost(int cost) {this.cost = cost;}

    /**
     * Sets the quantity of the need - necessary for JSON object to Java object deserialization
     * @param quantity The quantity of the need
     */
    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {this.quantity = quantity;}

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format(STRING_FORMAT,id,name,type,cost,quantity);
    }
}


Alright so I actually found the answer to my own question. For anyone out there wondering here is how to solve the issue:
I don't know if it is Spring or REST or JsonObjectMapper but one of these programs is causing the issue. Whichever program it is has a function that will not only look at what you specifically declared as JsonPropertys, but will also look inside the class functions. In an attempt to optimize storing the JSON data to a file it will reevaluate what it should store in the file based on what is in your function implementations. In my particular case, the program decided that it needed to store my internal ArrayList implementation variables into the file rather than the primitive array that I told it to store with @JsonProperty. The way to fix the problem and similar problems is to only use classes that can be cast to JSON in your class implementation. Here is my finished cart class which runs properly:
package com.ufund.api.ufundapi.model;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;

/**
 * Represents a Cart entity
 * 
 */
@JsonPropertyOrder({"id, needs"})
public class Cart {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(Cart.class.getName());

    static final String STRING_FORMAT = "Cart [id=%d, needs=%s]";

    @JsonProperty("id") private int id;
    @JsonProperty("needs") private Need[] needs;

     /**
     * Create a cart with the given id and map of needs.
     * @param id the id of the cart
     * @param needs the list of needs in the cart.
     * 
     * {@literal @} JsonProperty is used in serialization and deserialization
     * of the JSON object to the Java object in mapping the fields.  If a field
     * is not provided in the JSON object, the Java field gets the default Java
     * value, i.e. 0 for int.
     */
    public Cart(@JsonProperty("id") int id, @JsonProperty() Need[] needs) {
        this.id = id;
        this.needs = needs;
    }

    public int getId() {return id;}

    public Need[] getNeeds() {return needs;}

    public Boolean addNeed(Need n) {
        Need[] needArr = new Need[needs.length + 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < needs.length; i++) {
            if(needs[i].getId() == n.getId())
            return false;
            needArr[i] = needs[i];
        }
        needArr[needs.length] = n;
        needs = needArr;
        return true;
    }

    public Boolean updateNeed(int id, int quantity) {
        for (Need need: needs)
        {
            if(id == need.getId())
            {
                need.setQuantity(quantity);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Boolean deleteNeed(int id) {
        if(needs.length == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        int shift = 0;
        Need[] needArr = new Need[needs.length - 1];
        for (int i = 0; i < needs.length; i++)
        {
            if(id == needs[i].getId()) {
                shift = -1;
            }
            else if(i == needArr.length && shift == 0) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                needArr[i + shift] = needs[i];
            }
        }
        needs = needArr;
        return true;
    }

    public void checkout() {
        needs = new Need[0];
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return String.format(STRING_FORMAT, id, needs.toString());
    }
}

